# How to approach in-game character creation system alike Sims

Tags: unity, 3d, blender, character

I would like to implement an in-game character creation similar to the Wii/Mii system or The Sims using Blender and Unity. In what ways is this possible, other than (or in conjunction with) using shape keys? The ideal system would have 2-4 body types, ~8 hairstyles, full RGB skin/hair toning (I quite like Terraria's style), and a few styles for faces.

I have been looking into this topic, but so far I have not found a good explanation as to how this would be implemented, and blender shape keys would allow for some aspects of this - namely body and hair manipulation - but would not work for coloring or styling the face.

Comment: http://www.makehuman.org/ is an open source program for generating parametrised humanoid meshes, you could look at the source to see how it works. (It can also export to blender.)

Answer (score 1):

You kind of summed up what you would have to do to create a ingame character creation screen.
Supply different models for hair, face, and body. As for different colors, use a shader when drawing the model. The shader can make your skin color black, white, yellow or whatever stereotype color you would need.

I feel like there is not much to say about this currently as there is not a real problem. Could you emphasize the part you had difficulties with while implementing it. You did try something, right?